# SQL (Omnisci) get common and uncommon values of a column

Tags: sql, omniscidb

I'm using Omnisci to join two tables and I need the following:

Table 1:

```
poly_id | num_competitors
   1    |     1
   2    |     1
   3    |     5
```

Table 2:

```
    poly_id | num_stores
       1    |     1
       5    |     3
       7    |     5
```

What I want:

```
 poly_id | num_competitors | num_stores
       1    |     1        |    1
       2    |     1        |    0
       3    |     5        |    0
       5    |     0        |    3
       7    |     0        |    5
```

I know in normal SQL you can do it with FULL JOIN or even with UNION, but Omnisci does not support any of these functions yet (it does support JOIN and LEFT JOIN though).

Comment: How do they call it "SQL" if it doesn't support `UNION`?

Comment: I guess they rely on the fact that the structure of the data is relational as SQL and it supports most of the functionalities that SQL provides. The thing is that this is a tool thought to work with geospatial and big data problems (it also supports most of the functionalities of PostGIS), so maybe they avoided to implement`UNION` because it could be highly inefficient. 

If you want to know more you can check their documentation https://docs.omnisci.com/latest/index.html

Answer (score 1):

I've found a way to solve it. It's by creating a new empty table. Insert into it Table 1 and Table 2 and then make a group by on poly id in order to merge rows that have both num_competitors and num_stores.

```
CREATE TABLE competitors_stores ( poly_id integer, num_stores integer, num_competitors integer);

INSERT INTO competitors_stores ( SELECT poly_id, 0, num_competitors from competitors_geo)

INSERT INTO competitors_stores ( SELECT poly_id, num_stores, 0 from telepi_stores_geo)

CREATE TABLE num_competitors_stores AS (select poly_id, SUM(num_stores) AS num_stores, SUM(num_competitors) as num_competitors from competitors_stores group by poly_id);

DROP TABLE telepi_competitors_stores;
```

Anyway, I'm still open to hearing alternatives since I feel like this is not the best way to solve it.